# Using external libraries in Karate framework

Tags: karate

I would like to use external JS libraries such as JsonQ.js(https://github.com/s-yadav/jsonQ) for validating my complex JSON response. Can some one guide me on how to plug external libraries and use them as part of Karate feature files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need an external library to validate any complex JSON responses in Karate framework. Karate's built-in capability is really strong enough to do any JSON validations. I used to work on projects which will give complex JSON responses which can be very easily validated using Karate. Using Karate you can validate

- Any key & values
- JSON Objects, JSON arrays
- Subsets of JSON's from a response
- You can iterate and check values
- Headers
- Status
- Fuzzy Matching (Check null, boolean, string,  etc)
- Use regular expressions for validations
- JSON schema validations etc

I would suggest going through the documentation and webinars of Karate to understand the details of validation capabilities.

- https://github.com/intuit/karate
- https://www.techgig.com/webinar/Karate-DSL-for-writing-web-service-API-acceptance-tests-BDD-1042
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2092&v=YWK4J3lhFw4

Comment: It is not very clear how I can filter a JSON response down to a single JSON node.  In Karate how do you do something like this pseudo-code: `response.filter("{AField: 'matchingTxt'}").findFirst().TargetAttribute`??   Seems pretty necessary to be able to do this for most testing purposes.

Comment: Ok, i found the answer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms